# lighthouse auditing : Avoid an excessive DOM size , what is the best practice to have 2000 options in select tag with out affecting the performance?

Tags: html, performance, dom, lighthouse

i'm trying to fix the performance issues reported by lighthouse.
one of these issues is select tag has about 2000 options
so light house telling me " avoid an excessive DOM size : A large DOM will increase memory usage, cause longer style calculations, and produce costly layout reflows "

Example :

```
<select>
<option>2000</option>
<option>1999</option>
<option>1998</option>
.
.
.
<option>1</option>
</select>
```

I used pugjs to generate the 2000 options

what do you think the best practice would be to avoid this performance issue ?

Comment: Do they have to use a select field, or can they just input a number in a text box from 1 to 2000 and have it validated before submitting the form?

Comment: I know this is gonna be the best solution but is there any way to handle this ? , and is this issue really affect the performance?